# Build error Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0

Tags: node.js, npm

My build server on Visual Studio Team Services (aka VSO) is failing with the following error message. Any idea how I can fix this?

> npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer
>   maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.

The error is caused by the following line in my project.json file

> "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp
>   min" ]

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: NPM uses `package.json` file to install needed modules. As it seems it's outdated, try opening it and putting there `lodash@^3.0.0` instead of `lodash@1.0.2`

Comment: You probably have a dependency in your project that insists on using `lodash@1.0.2` (you can run `npm ls lodash@1` to find out which one). Perhaps there's a later version of that dependency you can use, or otherwise, see if you can just ignore the warning as it's only there to tell you that it's really old (but that won't stop it from functioning)

Comment: I don't have any experience with NodeJs. I opened the NodeJs Interactive Window in Visual Studio 2015 and typed "npm ls loadash@1" but I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error.

Comment: The message you see is just a warning message. It should not fail the build. Is there any other error message in the build task? If yes, can you provide the detail error log?

Comment: I hate to do this but this doesn't sound like and ASP.NET/VS specific issue. It seems like an node/npm problem

Comment: FWIW I'm getting the same message because lodash 1.0.2 is in the dependency tree of node-sass-middleware 0.8.0 but for me it is just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Gulp 3.9.0 - in need of updating dependencies. You can try to do it yourself or wait for new version.

Answer (score 0):

Update version using below command :

```
$npm update lodash@3
```